# Don't lose the current command when up is pressed in a terminal

Tags: bash, command-history

How can I configure my Linux terminal so that the current command isn't lost when I press the up arrow key?

Comment: If you press the down key it should come back (assuming bash).
This is part of bash's history ability - every time you press up, you see the previous command, pressing down you see the most recent, including what you just typed.  Effectively, in this instance, your 'undo'.

Comment: It doesn't comeback when you type fast.

Comment: What shell are you using & which terminal configuration (echo $SHELL; echo $TERM).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
bind -r "\e[A"
```

Then save the file. This will take effect when you open your next terminal (load it immediately with `. <file>` or `source <file>`).

This will unbind the Up arrow key from accessing your history. You can still use <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd> to move to the previous history item and <kbd>ctrl+N</kbd> to move to the next history item.

To unbind both up and down arrow keys, use this:

```
bind -r "\e[A"
bind -r "\e[B"
```